# Pinpoint is not delivering push notification on Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I am using aws mobileHub for my react-native project. I am using aws-amplify library to use aws features in my app and i follow all the steps of aws-Pinpoint and aws-amplify for push notifications in android . When app open I get the token from 'aws-amplify-react-native' but when I start campaign it sometimes deliver few messages sometimes none but I received none of it and when I try direct messages then it says successfully send push notification from pinpoint console but I received nothing in app. Here is the image of success message

[image: Image of console]

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem? Do you use bare react native? or expoKit ?

Comment: found , expokit

Comment: What was the solution? I have similar problem

Comment: Please take a look at my issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3080 Maybe you can recommend me something.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind testing sending a test message using the AWS CLI. The reason is that the CLI would be able to give you a more detailed error message. It would look something like this.

```
aws pinpoint send-messages --application-id {appid} --message-request '{
    "Addresses": {
        "{token}": {
            "ChannelType": "GCM"
        }
    },
    "MessageConfiguration": {
        "GCMMessage": {
            "Body": "Test Body",
            "Title": "Test Title"
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully the response you get from this will tell you the reason why your requests are failing. My guess of what is wrong is that you somehow have an invalid token.